# raspberry pi and ltc 2873 cufd (RS 232 and RS 485)

Tags: pi-3, rpi.gpio, serial-console, readwrite, compute-module-3

I have a raspberry pi compute module 3 on an I/O board in which gpio 12 is contolling the mode in ltc 2873. If it is ground it will be working in the RS 232 mode. so if I have to write something into it which port should I be using for the serial communication . should I be using tty1 that is the port for Uart R_X and UART t_x itself. I am attaching the schematic along with this and I have to take the output from the JP3 section as in the schematic. Can someone pls help me figure it out.[image: asenter image description here]

Comment: I don't understand the problem you're having. You seem to ask which port you should use, but neither did you tell which ports you have available, nor did you present any arguments against using the tty1.

Comment: hii the ports availble in are the tty and usb ports. what I have with me is an I/O board of which the pins UART_RX and UART_tx are connected to the ltc 2873 and and the output (tx and rx) from it is taken directly from the ltc 2873. so how should I be writing into it. which port should I be using.and can I directly connect the tx and rx from ltc 2873 to any serial device or do I furthur need to keep any converter in between.